# What are the logs to check for a hung LAMP server?

Tags: centos5, lamp

I'm running Centos 5.7. I'm running Apache, MySQL, PHP, Courier-IMAP, Qmail and Plesk control panel in a typical Web hosting server setup. It gets hung often.

I had to restart the server via the admin panel, since there was no Plesk or SSH access... How to prevent this from happening again?

> Processor: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4
>   RAM: 8 GB

I noticed some errors in the Apache log:

```
# tail -20 /var/log/httpd/error_log

[Mon Sep 03 06:12:33 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/web
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:34 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/php-my-admin
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:34 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/websql
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:35 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpmyadmin
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:36 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:36 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:37 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/php-my-admin
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:38 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.2.3
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:38 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.2.6
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:39 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.1
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:39 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.4
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:40 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-rc1
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:41 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-rc2
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:41 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.5
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:42 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.5-pl1
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:43 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc1
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:43 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.6-rc2
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:44 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.6
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:45 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.7
[Mon Sep 03 06:12:45 2012] [error] [client 202.29.34.28] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpMyAdmin-2.5.7-pl1
```

Also noticed some mysql slow queries:

```
# Query_time: 23.734215  Lock_time: 0.000111 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 2501281
use yasooyam_yasoodb;
SET timestamp=1346149823;
SELECT COUNT(user_history_product.ID) FROM user_history_product WHERE user_history_product.PRODUCT_ID=915;

# Query_time: 293.916966  Lock_time: 1.163037 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 2501280
SET timestamp=1346149823;
SELECT COUNT(user_history_product.ID) FROM user_history_product WHERE user_history_product.PRODUCT_ID=172;

# Query_time: 61.295134  Lock_time: 0.000345 Rows_sent: 331  Rows_examined: 331
use pumexinf_mdb;
SET timestamp=1346149825;
show tables;

# Query_time: 16.869923  Lock_time: 2.281526 Rows_sent: 1889  Rows_examined: 9330
use yasooyam_yasoodb;
SET timestamp=1346586973;
SELECT user_items.ID, user_items.TYPE, user_items.USER_ID, user_items.SHOW_IN, user_items.CATEGORY, user_items.SUB_CATEGORY, user_items.COUNTRY, user_items.LANGUAGE, user_items.TITLE, user_items.START_TIME, user_items.END_TIME, user_items.DATE, user_items.DESCRIPTION, user_items.ATTACH, user_items.IMAGE, user_items.IMAGE_AUTHOR, user_items.IMAGE_SOURCE, user_items.VIDEO_URL, user_items.THUMB, user_items.AUTHOR, user_items.SOURCE, user_items.CREATE_DATE, user_items.UPDATE_DATE, user_items.STATUS FROM user_items WHERE user_items.TYPE=9 AND user_items.STATUS=1;
```

Comment: None of those log entries are directly relevant to your problem, although the MySQL query times are indicative of some process tying up the CPU. The Apache log entries should be self explanatory, you only need to read them.

Answer (score 1):

Hang is surely not the result of a fatal error of (file not found) - as per apache2 logs.

It depends on how much memory you have allowed in your my.cnf for mysqld.

You need to investigate a bit more about why this is hanging.

Few things to note for investigation:

- **Server hanging(denial of service) can be result of 2 things, over-processor load or an application causing denial of service.**
- **Check system log instead of application logs for more insights**
- **Have precautionary measures by installing [deflateDOS](http://deflate.medialayer.com/) and [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page) Check their logs**
- **Keep in mind commands like `top` and `netstat` they come in handy a lot.**

Comment: there is no my.ini. There is my.cnf. I'm a junior linux admin, please explain at the basic level. :)

Comment: yea, edited it :P I am not even an admin, I am just a developer *frowns*

Comment: query_cache_size=128M

Comment: I thought admins have the inferiority complex... including me.

Comment: We thought we look like an idiot when we call admin to fix an installation which required 'sudo' in the beginning of command. :S

Comment: I'm feeling particularly down as I don't have a senior admin to guide me...

Comment: even I have learnt things the hardway :) I am mostly on Stackexchange on Stackoverflow. Get started to learn, you gonna love it! By the way did you try solutions given by j0nes? I have edited my answer. Check bullet points.

Comment: @melvincv, why would admins have an inferiority complex? We're as good as anyone else and better than some.

Comment: yes, i'm installing Munin. Thanks for your tips too.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, once munin does the trick for you, please click on tick next to answer by j0nes, so that others in the community can refer to it as an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install a monitoring software like [Munin](http://www.munin-monitoring.org/). With munins plugins, you can monitor a lot of things over time. For example you can see a spike in Apache requests before the server hangs, or disk I/O, or mysql connections. With such a software in place, it is much easier to find the source for hangups.

Comment: which monitoring software is easier to use for a beginner?

Comment: I generally prefer munin. There are a lot of predefined plugins available already, and there are normally packages available for your linux distribution.

Comment: I'm installing Munin using http://www.howtoforge.com/server-monitoring-with-munin-and-monit-on-centos-5.2

Comment: I've been running Munin for almost 1 day, but I can only see dots in the graph... no real graphs. And please point me to a link to get plugins.

Comment: For some linux distributions there are already packages with plugins available. Otherwise have a look at [the munin contrib github repository](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/)

Comment: munin-node is running. What else could be causing the issue with only dots in the graph?

Comment: How may I go about diagnosing why Munin is running, but no graphs appear?